# Rx extensions/parallel task library in .net compact/xna3.1 for xbox360?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, parallel-processing, windows-phone-7

Is there any way I can use the .net task parallel library that was included in the Rx extensions for .net 3.5 SP1 in xna 3.1 for xbox 360? Or, alternatively, to use the Rx extensions themselves? The assemblies installed by .net 3.5 SP1 Rx extensions installer do not appear to be compatible with the .net compact framework.

Or, if not possible with xna 3.1, is it possible with xna 4.0? I know that the Rx extensions are available for windows phone (via Microsoft.Phone.Reactive), but not for xbox360 targets. However, the task parallel library doesn't appear to be available for use on either WP7 or xbox360 targets.

Comment: I'm not sure if you asked [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/fd344f71-2cf6-4dbe-8bc0-977762923ba8); the [Rx forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/threads) is the place to go for an answer (I haven't seen any of the Rx team on SO yet).

Comment: Yes, I asked on MSDN as well. Sometimes I get an answer on SO when I don't on MSDN, and sometimes on MSDN and not SO, so I tend to post on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference Microsoft.Phone.Reactive from an XNA project for the phone just like you can with a Silverlight project. Should just work... Not sure about its availability for Xbox 360, however.